# Euclidean distance with normalize dataframe in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I actually have a clustering project in R so i must calculate the euclidean distance of my normalise data (all are numeric types). But if i use the function "dist" i R to calculate my eucliden distance i the function count the number of observations( i have 1175  obaservations in my data so i got 1775 values).
I write an algorithm to calculate euclidean distance but i got the same thing with the "dist" function. Here is my code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M0re.png)
my normalize data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vOt.png) and my euclidean distance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPgSY.png)

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I highly recommend you include your code and a small representative sample of your data (using `dput()`) instead of sharing screenshots. It allows the community to reproduce your code and better help you!

Comment: You can normalize your data with `scale()`, you do not need to write your own function. If you use `scale(yourdata)`, it will normalize each column. If you have 1175 rows, your distance matrix will be 1175 rows by 1175 columns. The `dist()` function will compute only the lower triangle of that matrix since the upper triangle is the same and the diagonal is all 0s. So  `dist` will compute 1175*(1175-1)/2 = 689725 distances.